# Comparing information in nested loops and marking when they match

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops, nested

data is an array carrying:
  observation1, observation2, observation3, observation4, observation5

stringarray2 an array which may contain any of the above, eg:
  observation1, observation4

I am trying to add items into countryList, setting them true if they appear in both arrays, otherwise setting false.

I need help setting up the nested loops.

I currently have the below setup which is really close, but this only adds the last item in array 2 as true (eg, observation4)
  Can you see where I am going wrong please?

```
while (data.moveToNext()){

        if (data.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                observation = data.getString(1);

                if (editing.equals("yes")) {

                    stringarray2
                    Boolean test = false;
                    for (String name:stringarray2)
                    {
                        if (observation.equals(name)){
                            test = true;
                        }else{
                            test = false;
                        }
                    }

                    Country country = new Country(null,observation,test);
                    countryList.add(country);

                }else{
                    Country country = new Country(null,observation,false);
                    countryList.add(country);
                }
            }while(data.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (data.moveToFirst())
{
      do
      {
           observation = data.getString(1);

           if (editing.equals("yes")) 
           {
                stringarray2 //random word here?
                Boolean test = false;
                for (String name:stringarray2)
                {
                    if (observation.equals(name))
                    {
                        test = true; 
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Country country = new Country(null,observation,test);
                countryList.add(country);
            }
            else
            {
               Country country = new Country(null,observation,false);
               countryList.add(country);
            }
      }
      while (data.moveToNext())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is in your while and if condition.

With your first loop you have

```
while (data.moveToNext())
```

[moveToNext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToNext()) already *checks* if there is a next **and** *moves* to it, you shouldn't be moving to first again, just start using the value

You need something like

```
try {
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        observation = data.getString(1);

                if (editing.equals("yes")) {

                    stringarray2
                    Boolean test = false;
                    for (String name:stringarray2)
                    {
                        if (observation.equals(name)){
                            test = true;
                        }else{
                            test = false;
                        }
                    }

                    Country country = new Country(null,observation,test);
                    countryList.add(country);

                }else{
                    Country country = new Country(null,observation,false);
                    countryList.add(country);
                }
    }
} finally {
    data.close();
}
```

Assuming your inner logic is working fine.

P.S I added a `try finally`, because you need to close your cursor after your're done with the query result.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of moveToNext. This code still just selects the last item, but the marked answer works. I have added the try as you suggest. Im not sure why my question got voted down.